# Summarizing fields for view display in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a form design that populates with users' names that have requested information.  Included with the detail, a field exists that displays the total number of days it took for the person to respond to the request.  We have up to 10 fields that will hold the users' names and the number of days for the person to respond.

I am trying to summarize this so that I can display the information in a view as a summary of the detail.

Here is an example of the detail:

FieldName1 = Sally Jones   DaysProcess1  = 3

FieldName2 = John Smith    DaysProcess2  = 2

FieldName3 = Fred Johnson  DaysProcess3  = 1

FieldName4 = Sally Jones   DaysProcess4  = 4

FieldName5 = Fred Johnson  DaysProcess5  = 2

I would like to display in a view as such

Name  - Number Requests -Total Days

Sally Jones -  2  - 7

John Smith  -  1  - 2

Fred Johnson-  2  - 3

Your thoughts are much appreciated
Jean

Comment: Calculate the summary in a computed multivalue text field and show this field in a view column. Show entries in separate lines with property "Multi value separator: New Line" or "Show multiple values as separate entries". For calculating summary you can use Formula or LotusScript - whatever you like more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the easy part. The Name column can look like this:

`enter code here`@Unique(FieldName1 : FieldName2 : FieldName3 : FieldName4 : FieldName5);

Now let's look at the hard part. In the second column, you want the first value to be the 2 because Sally Jones has two entries, right?  Well, then your second column has to access the list of unique names, in order, and it has to count how many of the fields reference that name. This looks about right for your second column formula:

```
theUniqueNames := @Unique(FieldName1 : FieldName2 : FieldName3 : FieldName4 : FieldName5);
allTheNames := FieldName1 : FieldName2 : FieldName3 : FieldName4 : FieldName5;
output := @Transform(theUniqueNames; "x"; 
     @Elements(@Trim(@Replace(allTheNames;x;"")))
);
output;
```

The last column needs to be a sum of the DaysProcessX fields that correspond to the FieldNameX fields that you just just counted for each name. That's harder. I'm going to cheat here, and assume that you will never add any more pairs of fields to the form...

```
theUniqueNames := @Unique(FieldName1 : FieldName2 : FieldName3 : FieldName4 : FieldName5);
allTheNames := FieldName1 : FieldName2 : FieldName3 : FieldName4 : FieldName5;
output := @Transform(theUniqueNames; "x"; 
    @If(fieldName1 = x;DaysProcess1;0) +
    @If(fieldName2 = x;DaysProcess2;0) +
    @If(fieldName3 = x;DaysProcess3;0) +
    @If(fieldName4 = x;DaysProcess4;0) +
    @If(fieldName5 = x;DaysProcess5;0)
);       
output;
```

If you want to account for more pairs of fields in the future, a nested @Transform will probably do the trick, but that's a little too hairy to work out without actual testing. (*I.e., what I'm saying here is that the above is not tested. Hopefully it's close enough to give you the right idea.*)